# JMS custom payment plugin - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, jms

I am trying to create a custom payment method using JMS payment bundle for Symfony2.
I have the paypal bundle set up fine - however I want a 2nd option for pay by bank transfer.

Below is the code I have - but this isn't displaying a new payment option.

Form class:

```
namespace JMS\Payment\BanktransferBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class BanktransferType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
            ->add('holder', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('number', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('expires', 'date', array('required' => false))
            ->add('code', 'text', array('required' => false))
    ;
}

public function getName() {
    return 'credit_card';
}

}
```

Plugin class:

```
namespace JMS\Payment\BanktransferBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class BanktransferType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
            ->add('holder', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('number', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('expires', 'date', array('required' => false))
            ->add('code', 'text', array('required' => false))
    ;
}

public function getName() {
    return 'credit_card';
}

}
```

Services.yml

```
services:
payment.plugin.banktransfer:
    class: JMS\Payment\BanktransferBundle\Plugin\BanktransferPlugin
    tags: [{name: payment.plugin}]

credit_card_type:
    class: JMS\Payment\BanktransferBundle\Form\BanktransferType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: credit_card }
        - { name: payment.method_type }
```

What do I need to do in order for the JMS payment bundle to find my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I seemed to have got it showing by using XML instead of YML.

Services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema  /dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<parameters>
    <parameter key="payment.plugin.cash_checkout.class">JMS\Payment\CashBundle\Plugin\CashPlugin</parameter>
    <parameter key="payment.form.cash_checkout_type.class">JMS\Payment\CashBundle\Form\CashType</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="payment.form.cash_checkout_type" class="%payment.form.cash_checkout_type.class%">
        <tag name="payment.method_form_type" />
        <tag name="form.type" alias="cash_checkout" />
    </service>
</services>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us the real Plugin Class? I think you posted the wrong content.
I had the same problem and I followed the instructions based on the JMS [documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSPaymentCoreBundle/master/plugins).

My Plugin Class (minimal):

```
    <?php
    //...

    use \JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

    class DebitPlugin extends AbstractPlugin {
        public function processes($name) {
        return 'debit' === $name;
      }
    }
```

And in your controller you have to add the name, depending on your Plugin (in my case 'debit').

```
   <?php
   //...
   $form = $this->getFormFactory()->create('debit', null, array());
   //...
```

Hope that helps!